# sudo apt update repository error on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, repository

```
dev@dev-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 //http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                              
Hit:2 //http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:3 //https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                
Hit:4 //https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                   
Hit:5 //http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                                       
Ign:7 //http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease                                                                                                                            
Hit:8 //http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                                     
Hit:9 //https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                                                                                        
Hit:6 //https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Hit:10 //http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                
Ign:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease                                                                              
Err:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
Hit:13 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                        
Hit:14 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release                                   
Hit:16 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/./InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/5.0/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.


E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
```

I have tried removing the repository but it still does not work. Pl

Comment: Does a line for the impish repository appear in `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 is EOL thus errors on *impish* should be expected - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/